# R; Round up or down to a given X given a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
x = c(0.71428571, 0.23809524, 0.04761905)
```

I would like to round up or down based on the number in the vector to its nearest 0.05. So in the above example, I want to be able to get `x = c(0.70,0.25,0.05)`.

I have tried `round(x,2)` but that doesn't work out as i get `0.71 0.24 0.05`.

Also it should be able to generalize such that if I want it to the nearest 0.01 or 0.10, etc. So for example the above vector given `x = 0.10` would equal `c(0.70,0.20,0)`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+round+to+the+nearest

Comment: Not really an `R` question, as the solution depends on understanding rounding and sigfigs more than on code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```
nearest <- 0.05
((x + nearest/2) %/% nearest) * nearest
# [1] 0.70 0.25 0.05
```